# How to display the logo infinitely using css

Tags: html, css

I am displaying the logo infinitely but I am getting one issue. I mean in the end, I am getting the space. I want an infinite scroll.

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

ul li img {
  width: 100px;
}

.overflowHidden {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.marqueme {
  transform: translateZ(0);
  width: 1600px;
  -webkit-animation: d 40s linear infinite;
  animation: d 40s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes d {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(-100%, 0);
  }
}

.marqueme ul li {
  padding: 0 15px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container">
  <div class="overflowHidden">
    <div class="marqueme">
      <ul>

        <li>
          <a href=""><img src="https://e7.pngegg.com/pngimages/340/745/png-clipart-computer-icons-white-instagram-icon-text-logo.png"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href=""><img src="https://e7.pngegg.com/pngimages/340/745/png-clipart-computer-icons-white-instagram-icon-text-logo.png"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href=""><img src="https://e7.pngegg.com/pngimages/340/745/png-clipart-computer-icons-white-instagram-icon-text-logo.png"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href=""><img src="https://e7.pngegg.com/pngimages/340/745/png-clipart-computer-icons-white-instagram-icon-text-logo.png"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href=""><img src="https://e7.pngegg.com/pngimages/340/745/png-clipart-computer-icons-white-instagram-icon-text-logo.png"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href=""><img src="https://e7.pngegg.com/pngimages/340/745/png-clipart-computer-icons-white-instagram-icon-text-logo.png"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href=""><img src="https://e7.pngegg.com/pngimages/340/745/png-clipart-computer-icons-white-instagram-icon-text-logo.png"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href=""><img src="https://e7.pngegg.com/pngimages/340/745/png-clipart-computer-icons-white-instagram-icon-text-logo.png"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href=""><img src="https://e7.pngegg.com/pngimages/340/745/png-clipart-computer-icons-white-instagram-icon-text-logo.png"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href=""><img src="https://e7.pngegg.com/pngimages/340/745/png-clipart-computer-icons-white-instagram-icon-text-logo.png"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href=""><img src="https://e7.pngegg.com/pngimages/340/745/png-clipart-computer-icons-white-instagram-icon-text-logo.png"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href=""><img src="https://e7.pngegg.com/pngimages/340/745/png-clipart-computer-icons-white-instagram-icon-text-logo.png"></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

I am getting like this at the end.

[image]

Comment: Yes, you will get in full screen, wait for some time at the end you will get some space.

Comment: i noticed that so i deleted comment, but you'll need javascript for this

Comment: @cornonthecob, Is it possible using CSS?

Comment: not sure - don't think so though

Comment: Ok. so can you help me with the script till the time?

Answer (score 0):

**CSS only**

Animate your element inside `.marqueme` instead, the jump won't be noticeable because elements go back to the position of their siblings:

```
.marqueme {
  transform: translateZ(0);
  width: 1600px;
}

li {
  animation: d 1s linear infinite;
}
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

ul li img {
  width: 100px;
}

.overflowHidden {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.marqueme {
  transform: translateZ(0);
  width: 1600px;
}

li {
  animation: d 0.3s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes d {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(-100%, 0);
  }
}

.marqueme ul li {
  padding: 0 15px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container">
  <div class="overflowHidden">
    <div class="marqueme">
      <ul>

        <li>
          <a href=""><img src="https://e7.pngegg.com/pngimages/340/745/png-clipart-computer-icons-white-instagram-icon-text-logo.png"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href=""><img src="https://e7.pngegg.com/pngimages/340/745/png-clipart-computer-icons-white-instagram-icon-text-logo.png"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href=""><img src="https://e7.pngegg.com/pngimages/340/745/png-clipart-computer-icons-white-instagram-icon-text-logo.png"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href=""><img src="https://e7.pngegg.com/pngimages/340/745/png-clipart-computer-icons-white-instagram-icon-text-logo.png"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href=""><img src="https://e7.pngegg.com/pngimages/340/745/png-clipart-computer-icons-white-instagram-icon-text-logo.png"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href=""><img src="https://e7.pngegg.com/pngimages/340/745/png-clipart-computer-icons-white-instagram-icon-text-logo.png"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href=""><img src="https://e7.pngegg.com/pngimages/340/745/png-clipart-computer-icons-white-instagram-icon-text-logo.png"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href=""><img src="https://e7.pngegg.com/pngimages/340/745/png-clipart-computer-icons-white-instagram-icon-text-logo.png"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href=""><img src="https://e7.pngegg.com/pngimages/340/745/png-clipart-computer-icons-white-instagram-icon-text-logo.png"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href=""><img src="https://e7.pngegg.com/pngimages/340/745/png-clipart-computer-icons-white-instagram-icon-text-logo.png"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href=""><img src="https://e7.pngegg.com/pngimages/340/745/png-clipart-computer-icons-white-instagram-icon-text-logo.png"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href=""><img src="https://e7.pngegg.com/pngimages/340/745/png-clipart-computer-icons-white-instagram-icon-text-logo.png"></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

PS: you need way less li elements (and add them a class to target the class instead of targeting li)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Give me some time to check

Comment: you might want to slow the effect down :) too fast!

Comment: Gotta go fast! (I agree, that's to demonstrate it quickly, it was frustrating to wait 40s, I trust the author and readers to change the value)

Comment: @devdgehog, Yes, I checked and it's working but I notice that, If I added more li (min 4 to 5) then it's not working. Do I need to change width?

Comment: Yes, if you hardcoded the width then it won't work if the width of the content is less than the width of the parent, that's another problem, you could (for example as a quick fix) use `ul li img { width: 100%; }` or you can set a height to your container and use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit and padding on your images.

Comment: @devdgehog, Apologize for the late reply. I  checked  your snippet and it's working but if I add more li then I am not getting infinite https://jsfiddle.net/vsdwkfha/

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```css
.imageSlider {
  background: white;
  background-image: url(https://e7.pngegg.com/pngimages/340/745/png-clipart-computer-icons-white-instagram-icon-text-logo.png);
  background-size: 260px;
  width: 400%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  left: -100%;
  animation: slide 12.2s infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  z-index: 1;
}

.marqueme {
  position: fixed;
  width: 80%;
  height: 200px;
  z-index: 2;
}

@keyframes slide {
  0% {
    left: -100%;
  }
  100% {
    left: 0%;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container">
  <div class="overflowHidden">
    <div class="marqueme">
      <div class="imageSlider"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry about the little glitch, I did not know the exact time needed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I have different logos and there are some jerk issues in your answer